# Why is my Float words setting its self to 0 without me setting it, this is the only script with .SetFloat Been scratching my head for the past 3h

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Scriptname : MonoBehaviour
{
   private string Words;
   public float ShowPrefs;

   private void Start()
   {
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("C");
       
        Words = this.gameObject.name;
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(Words, 2);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
   }

   private void Update()
   {
        ShowPrefs = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(Words);

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(Words) == 2)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(Words);
        }
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(Words) == 1)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(Words, 1);
        }
     }

     private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
     {
           if (other.gameObject.name == Words)
           {
                 PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(Words, 1);
                 PlayerPrefs.Save();
           }
           else
           { 
                 PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(Words, 2);
                 PlayerPrefs.Save();
           }
     }
}
```

The `Playerpref.GetFloat(Words)`; is setting itself to `0` for some reason even if I restart my unity many times. Been Googling and not finding my answers online so am asking here, if anyone know please kindly help me with my foolish brain, thank you!

Comment: Because you delete it in `if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(Words) == 2) { PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(Words); }` ...? Set a breakpoint there and check if it is called ...

Comment: @derHugo 
Yes i dont think it make a difference tho, i have deleted that part of the code but it still doesnt erase the 0

Comment: Why should it erase the `0`? As long as there is no such key given in the `PlayerPrefs` the `GetFloat` will return the default value `0` ... right at the beginning you did `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(Words, 2);` and then in the very first `Update` call you already do `PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(Words);` since it was set to `2` already ... I think this matters a lot ^^

Comment: @derHugo yes what am saying is i deleted the if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(Words) == 2) { PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(Words); } part and its still returning 0 when i didnt set it to 0, so at the start its setting it to 2 instead of 0 but its not showing 2 but is showing 0.

Comment: https://s4.gifyu.com/images/PainPrefs.gif ill make a gif to show u what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Start` you do

```
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(Words, 2);
```

so in the very first `Update` it matches

```
if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(Words) == 2)
```

so you do

```
PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(Words);
```

which means in the next frame

```
ShowPrefs = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(Words);
```

will return `0`.

The same happens if you collide wit anything that is not matching the name.

---

This

```
if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(Words) == 1)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(Words, 1);
}
```

is pretty unnecessary ... if the value `1` is already stored, then what good is it to store he same value again?

---

So if I simply comment out that block

```
//if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(Words) == 2)
//{
//    PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(Words);
//}
```

it works for me as "expected" (I guess)

[image]

Comment: Yep what i meant was i have deleted the PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(Words);
 part from my script and ran it again, it just flashes between 1 and 0

Comment: @Opman see the bottom of the answer .. can't reproduce it so it has to be related to something else then ...

Comment: well i dont know what is it anymore

Comment: Instead Of **Playerprefs** that is making Unity Confused i have used **Scriptable Objects** which work fine ;>